# Rewrite /ping to index.php/ping on nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have started off with a docker image which has a processor for php files in place.
Requesting the normal index.php file goes without issue, but the routes I added are less accessible.
One of the routes for example is /time, accessing this is done (with the php builtin webserver) with
index.php/time, and it would return me the time. Now the docker I used has php working perfectly, just that I think one of the rules is breaking this functionality for me. tried a lot of changes, but cant seem to find the issue.

```
$app->get('/time', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        // Current Unix timestamp
        $seconds = time();
        // Current Unix timestamp with microseconds
        $milliseconds = microtime(true)*1000;
        // Nanosecond precision
        // This is default as per InfluxDB standard
        $nanoseconds = $milliseconds*1000000;
        // Return
        return $response->withJson(array(
                'seconds' => $seconds,
                'milliseconds' => intval($milliseconds),
                'nanoseconds' => intval($nanoseconds)
        ), 200);
});
```

This is the configuration of the nginx server I am serving in the docker. One of the things I have tried is adding the location /ping { line. But to no avail, /ping, /time keep redirecting to a 404 not found.

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/www/html/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name _;

        # Disable sendfile as per https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html
        sendfile off;

        # Add stdout logging
        error_log /dev/stdout info;
        access_log /dev/stdout;

        # Add option for x-forward-for (real ip when behind elb)
        #real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
        #set_real_ip_from 172.16.0.0/12;

        location /ping {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/ping;
        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
                root /var/www/errors;
                internal;
        }

        location ^~ /sad.svg {
            alias /var/www/errors/sad.svg;
            access_log off;
        }
        location ^~ /twitter.svg {
            alias /var/www/errors/twitter.svg;
            access_log off;
        }
        location ^~ /gitlab.svg {
            alias /var/www/errors/gitlab.svg;
            access_log off;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on socket
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|webp|tiff|ttf|svg)$ {
                expires           5d;
        }

        # deny access to . files, for security
        #
        location ~ /\. {
                log_not_found off;
                deny all;
        }

        location ^~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
                auth_basic off;
        }

}
```

Comment: The `/index.php/ping` URI doesn't match your `\.php$` regex for PHP scripts processing. You could use `\.php($|/)` instead.

Comment: It does help processing the urls, but they all return 200. It is not expected, since it doesnt actually excecute the php path

Comment: What happens if you remove `try_files $uri =404;` from that block?